# HTML radio button text is shown first and later button image

Tags: html

Below is my code, I am not understanding why the text is shown to the left.

```html
<label for="dfg" id="OS">
                On which OS device do you play? <br>
            </label>
<input type="radio" name="OS" id="Android" value="android" required>Android <br>
<input type="radio" name="OS" id="IOS" value="ios" required>IOS <br>
<input type="radio" name="OS" id="Other" value="other" required>Other <br>
```

Comment: You question is not clear. What don't you understand?

Comment: From your code, the text is appearing on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused as I had set `width: 100%`

I'm learning web development and learnt big lesson whenever something is looking weird; first look at the CSS

Answer (score 1):

It is not so good to do that

```
<input type="radio" name="OS" id="IOS" value="ios" required>IOS <br>
```

because the text(IOS) is child of container or body at all so that's why you have call something like `label` tag and it will looks like

```
<input type="radio" name="OS" id="Android" value="android" required><label>Android</label> <br>
```

and the text will appear on the right of radio input while the following

```
<label>Android</label><input type="radio" name="OS" id="Android" value="android" required> <br>
```

text will appear on the left side of radio input and also `label` it is not the only tag to embed text for `input` but also you can use something like `span`, `div` and so on if you have any special reason